# Weak Mathematical Induction for Modulo Arithmetic $8\mid 3^{2n}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

Using Weak Mathematical Induction, I have to show that, for all integers $n \geq 1$, 
$8|3^{2n} -1$

I really don't know how to go about solving this problem. Currently I only have the base case and the Inductive Hypothesis:

Base Case: For $n = 1$
$$8|3^{2(1)}-1 = 8|8 = 0$$

Inductive Hypothesis:
Assume true for $n = k$
$$8|3^{2k}-1$$

Inductive Step:
I want to show that the statement is true for $n = k+1$
so $$8|3^{2(k+1)}-1$$

This is where I am currently stuck. Any help would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I have the right thought process for this, but in general for a ≡ b (mod n) can be written as n|(a-b) similarly for this problem I did 3^(2(k+1)) ≡ 1 (mod 8) Then I get stuck again.

Comment: This thought process deserves to be part of the main question. It is a significant idea that you contributed on your own. Even if it were useless (and it is not!) it would guide people to make more helpful responses.

Comment: You have written some things that are not grammatical, and so show only a partial understanding of the concepts. When you write “$a|b$”, you have made a *statement* that’s either true or false. It doesn’t have a value. So, “$8|8$” is *true*, but nothing you have written is equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

$8$ divides $3^{2k}-1$ then $3^{2k}=8m+1$ for some $m$.

$3^{2(k+1)}-1 = 3^{2k} \cdot 3^2-1 = (8m+1) \cdot 3^2-1 = 8m \cdot 3^2+3^2-1 = 8m \cdot 3^2+8$ which is divisible by 8.

Answer (score 0):

You are on a good path when you consider that $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$
is equivalent to $n | (a-b).$

In the inductive step, you already have $8|(3^{2k}-1),$
so you can write
$$3^{2k} \equiv 1 \pmod 8.$$
Now consider how to replace the "?" in
$$\frac{3^{2(k+1)}}{3^{2k}} \equiv \; ? \pmod 8$$
and see if these two facts help you show that
$$3^{2(k+1)} \equiv 1 \pmod 8.$$